# How to remove word containing '\u200' as subword?

Tags: python-3.x, csv

I have a csv file with bengali characters. So, when I extracted each words from the file, I found out many of the words contained '\u200' as subword. e.g, *জন\u200d্যও*. Now, I really want to get rid of such words but when I do `if 'u200' in word: print(word)`, it doesn't print anything. Searched whole web and there wasn't any such question. Thank you in advance.

Comment: `word.encode('ascii', 'ignore').decode('utf-8')`

Comment: should I put this when I extract words from csv file or in the if-check? Cause in if-check, it doesn't work.

Comment: Yes. The print function in python removes these Unicode. For example: 
`sample=[' \u200fضصثقفغعه\u200f ']` and then run these two lines:
`print(sample)`
`print(sample[0])`

If you run this, you can see that print doesn't show the Unicode.

I finally solved this by a little manual solution with this:

`result.append(mystring.replace('\u200c',''))`

Answer (score 0):

This solution does not completely solve your problem but solves some parts of it.
I tried many solutions like [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13726429/regex-string-replace) but didn't work.

This solves the problem but removes only `\u200d` and needs to generalize it for all strings that contain `\u200` or do the same for similar Unicode like `\u200f`and`\u200b`.

You can use this line of code to remove `\u200d`:

```
result=[]
result.append(mystring.replace('\u200d',''))
```